# Interpretation of the timescale non-dimensionalizing $\partial_t c(x,t) = - \frac{\dot{s}x}{s}\partial_x c + D \partial_x^2c$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, brownian-motion, fluid-dynamics, boundary-layer

**Background:**

A thin filament of fluid mixes into a flow field in accord with the so-called "compression-diffusion equation" (CDE), which is essentially an advection-diffusion equation with a particular space-time dependent velocity field $u(x,t) = \dot{s}(t)x/s(t)$. The variable $s(t)$ is the time-dependent thickness of the filament, and the quantity $\dot{s}/s$ is the compression rate of the filament induced by the flow. This compression rate depends on the specifics of the flow field in question, see [this paper](https://www.annualreviews.org/content/journals/10.1146/annurev-fluid-010518-040306).

The CDE has the following form:
$$ \partial_t c(x,t) = - \frac{\dot{s}(t)x}{s(t)}\partial_x c(x,t) + D \partial_x^2 c(x,t). $$
One can make the so-called ``Ranz transformation" to variables
$$ \tau(t) = D \int_0^t \frac{dt'}{s(t')^2}$$
$$ \xi(x,t) = \frac{x}{s(t)},$$
and this provides the canonical diffusion equation:
$$ \partial_\tau c(\xi,\tau) = \partial_\xi^2 c(\xi,\tau).$$
Therefore, the solution to the compression-diffusion equation is
$$ c(x,t) = \frac{c_0}{\sqrt{1+4\tau(t)}}\exp\left(- \frac{x^2}{s(t)^2(1+4\tau(t))}\right),$$
for an arbitrary $s(t)$ and initial condition $c(x,0)=c_0e^{-x^2/s_0^2}$. Clearly, the Ranz transformation greatly simplifies a challenging PDE to provide an exact solution.

**Question:**

**I would like to better interpret the variable $\tau$ which enacts this transformation.**  I understand that $\tau$ encodes a trade-off between the compression and diffusion terms, but I am not sure how to show this. **I am interested to find a derivation of the variable $\tau$, perhaps from a dominant balance argument.** Further, I would be interested for any physical explanation of why this is the timescale in which the CDE becomes canonical.

**Attempt:**

At short times $\tau(t)\ll 1$, the compression term dominates the CDE, while at long times $\tau(t)\gg 1$, the diffusion term dominates. This trade-off of compression-dominated to diffusion-dominated behavior originates from the fact that the compression term amplifies the concentration gradients ($\partial_x c$) which in turn fuel the diffusive flux ($J=-D\partial_x c$).
The limit $\tau=1$  describes equal influence of the compression and diffusion terms, and the resulting timescale $t_B$, defined by
$$ 1 = D\int_0^{t_B} \frac{dt'}{s(t')^2},$$
is known as the Batchelor time (in reference to George Batchelor).

I thought it may be possible to find the advection and diffusion-dominated solutions, then merge the two to find $\tau(t)$ and thereby gain insight into its meaning. In the advection-dominated regime, we have
$$ \partial_t c = -( \dot{s}x/s ) \partial_x c, $$
for which it is challenging for me to find a solution (which could be called $c_<(x,t)$, while the diffusive regime we have
$$ \partial_t c = D\partial_x^2 c, $$
which has solution $c_>(x,t) = \frac{c_0}{\sqrt{4Dt}}\exp(-x^2/(4Dt)).$
Perhaps it is possible to solve the advection-dominated problem and merge the solution via matched asymptotic expansions to discover the Batchelor time divides the two?

**Note on tags**
This problem is equivalent to Brownian motion in an inhomogeneous environment. It also relates to boundary layers in the sense of matched asymptotic expansions. I am attempting to cast a wide net.

Comment: reminds me of the Cole-Hopf transformation. Are they related?